# How to force user to attach file (file_field can not be blank) in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, null, paperclip, attachment

I am creating a podcast website with rails. When the user uploads a new episode to his/her account I want them to have to upload a podcast (mp3 file) and a thumbnail for that podcast (jpeg/png).

The problem is when I try to create the column for the mp3 and the thumbnail in SQLite it won't let me have a "not null" column with an initial value null.

I don't want default not null values, I want to FORCE them to attach files when they upload new episodes.

I am using paperclip to generate the migration for attachment columns "rails g paperclip user attachment"

This is the migration file for thumbnails, I have another similar file for MP3s.

```
class AddAttachmentThumbnailToEpisodes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :episodes do |t|
      t.attachment :thumbnail, null: false
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :episodes, :thumbnail
  end
end
```

It won't let me `rake db:migrate` this

Comment: Validation is not an option? Something like `validates_presence_of :thumbnail, :mp3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle it two ways

`#1` *Put a validation in the model*

```
validates :attachment, presence: true
```

***OR***

`#2` *You can handle it in the form with `required: true` option*

```
<%= f.file_field :attachment, required: true %>
```